# Azure Datafactory Ingestion JSON Format

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I'm doing some research into cloudbased ETL/ELT systems that can work with deeply nested JSON / XML Documents.

I found Azure Datafactory which seems to meet my requirements. However the documentation left me unsure about whether Datafactory can work with those deeply nested Documents. In the examples I found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json all objects are "flat", with zero nesting.

My question is: Does Datafactory Support nested Documents?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to ingest the data from nested JSON  file by using azure databricks. Reference link: 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/complex-nested-data.html